# Unity interception behind the scenes

Tags: unit-testing, inversion-of-control, aop

I wonder how Unity interception works behind the scenes? I mean interface,transparent proxy and virtual method proxy interceptors implementation.
Anyone could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that it uses either TransparentProxy or Reflection.Emit and TypeBuilder to dynamically create proxy types